# Updating a column in sql

Tags: sql

I am trying to update the data in a particular column according to the data in another column.
Some thing like below.

```
Name            ImageName
----------      -----------
aaa             no_image.jpg
bbb             no_image.jpg
ccc             no_image.jpg
ddd             no_image.jpg
```

I like to update this table something like below.

```
Name            ImageName
----------      -----------
aaa             aaa.jpg
bbb             bbb.jpg
ccc             ccc.jpg
ddd             ddd.jpg
```

Please find the sqlfiddle from the following link.
[SqlFiddle Link](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6e238/2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply do this in an `UPDATE` query itself.

Try this:

```
UPDATE table1
SET ImageName=Name+'.jpg'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Update table1
set imagename= name+'.jpg';
```

Answer (score 2):

```
update table1 set ImageName=concat(Name,substr(ImageName, instr(ImageName,'.')));
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually i think you need to put where statement because some columns might already have image name 
*update images t set t.image_name=t.name||'.jpg' where t.image_name='no_image.jpg'*